# Can't get corner radius to work

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners, cornerradius

Hi Im programming an chat app and i wan't the profile pictures to have a corner radius. This is my code. Btw Im using Parse as backend.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var imageView = PFImageView()
    let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.file = user[PF_USER_PICTURE] as? PFFile
    cell.textLabel?.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME] as? String
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(24)
    cell.imageView?.image = imageView.image



    return cell
}
```

UPDATE:
The problem was that my cell.imageview did not have a frame.
Thanks for the answer Max K!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You applied cornerRadius to layer of imageView created here:

`var imageView = PFImageView()`

But then you are using only its **image** property and assigning it to cell`s imageView:

`cell.imageView?.image = imageView.image`

Apply `cornerRadius` to cell's `imageView`.

Comment: When i try that i get this error: 'UIImageView' does not have a member named 'cornerRadius' –

Comment: Apply to layer, but layer of cell`s imageView, not that one you created.

Comment: I tried with     cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2 and it does not give me an error but the image is still square

Comment: @JohanEnstam in your original code the `imageView` (`PFImageView`) does not have established frame since you nor added it to screen neither set the frame explicitly

Comment: Ok and how to I establish the frame?

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageView = PFImageView()
```

is a different image view than:

```
cell.imageView?.image = imageView.image
```

What shows on screen is the image view of your cell not this instance of `PFImageView`. If you want to have `PFImageView` in as a class of your's cell's image view you need to set that, either in the storyboard or by subclassing your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `cornerRadius` on `imageView` that is not added to the screen later.

You have to set it on `cell.imageView`

```
if let imageView = cell.imageView {
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
}
```

Comment: When i try that i get this error: 'UIImageView' does not have a member named 'cornerRadius'

Comment: @JohanEnstam, my bad, of course it should be `imageView.layer.cornerRadius`. See the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding corner to the `imageView` in

> var imageView = PFImageView()

Instead add corner to the `cell.imageView`. It seems like you are using PFImageView to download image from a file. So you can modify the code like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

var imageView = PFImageView()
let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.file = user[PF_USER_PICTURE] as? PFFile
cell.textLabel?.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME] as? String
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(24)
cell.imageView?.image = imageView.image

return cell
}
```

Or else make imageView of `cell.imageView` as PFImageView